# Work with the "In_Memory" users of Symfony in a Controller

Tags: php, ajax, symfony, login-control

I am implementing a personalized Login Controller to access the admin section.

I would like to use the pre-configured "In_Memory" users provided by security.yml.

How could I access these users programmatically in my controller ?

I am using Ajax to submit the credentials to the Verification Action in the Controller.

This is my security.yml configuration

```
providers:
    in_memory:
        memory:
            users:
                user:  { password: userpass, roles: [ 'ROLE_USER' ] }
                admin: { password: adminpass, roles: [ 'ROLE_ADMIN' ] }


firewalls:
    backend:
        pattern:    ^/Admin/.*
        anonymous: true
        provider:  in_memory
        form_login:
            login_path: admin_controller_login
            check_path: admin_controller_login
```

And this is the Login Action

```
 public function LoginSubmitAction()
{



  $username = $_POST["username"];
  $password = $_POST["password"];


$login_status = 'invalid';

if($username == 'admin' && $password == 'adminpass')
 {
  $login_status = 'success';
  }

$resp['login_status'] = $login_status;



if($login_status == 'success')
{


   $resp['redirect_url'] =  'redirect_url';
 }
   echo json_encode($resp);      
     return new Response();

  }
```

Comment: What code have you tried so far in your Controller?

Comment: @Joey Ciechanowicz I have edited the question and included my code.

Answer (score 1):

One of the best reasons to use Symfony is its fantastic security layer, which has been reviewed by experts. Bypassing that is dangerous and pointless, as you're likely to waste lots of time getting it horribly wrong, when there is a perfectly good implementation already built in.

Just use the standard Symfony authentication library, which works happily with in memory users. If you need something that the `in_memory` users implementation don't offer, look at the [FOS User Bundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle).